# Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения

Tags: c#, исключения

Есть программа, которая обращается к стороннему API 14 раз в цикле(из первого ответа парсится список из 13 элементов которые потом поочередно опрашиваются), обращение выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class MyWebRequest
    {
        private WebRequest request;
        private Stream dataStream;

        private string status;

        public String Status
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
            set
            {
                status = value;
            }
        }

        public MyWebRequest(string url)
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.

            request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        }

        public MyWebRequest(string url, string method)
            : this(url)
        {

            if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
            {
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
                request.Method = method;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
            }
        }

        public MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data)
            : this(url, method)
        {

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = data;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();

        }

        public string GetResponse()
        {
            // Get the original response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

            // Get the stream containing all content returned by the requested server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            // Read the content fully up to the end.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return responseFromServer;
        }

    }
```

Если запрос заведомо должен получить небольшой по объему ответ все обрабатывается корректно, иначе ловлю

> System.IO.IOException не обработано
> Message="Не удается прочитать данные
> из транспортного соединения: Попытка
> чтения или записи в защищенную память.
> Это часто свидетельствует о том, что
> другая память повреждена.."

13 ответов выгружаю в RichTextBox, но до 2'147'483'647 символов там еще ой как далеко. Что может являться причиной ?

Comment: Повреждённая память означает ошибку в нативном коде. У вас нет в приложении нативных компонент?

Comment: Нативного, насколько я понимаю в нативном коде и компонентах, ничего нет

Я тут подумал, не будет ли подниматься такое исключение если сторонний API не стал отвечать на запрос? Пришел пустой ответ, например. Такое возможно?

Может быть существуют какие-то ограничения транспортного уровня о которых я не знаю? Может на нем недопустимо так часто создавать, открывать и закрывать соединения?

Comment: Есть еще какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Мистика :). А на другой машине запускать пробовали? Может действительно проблема в поврежденной памяти? Да, кстати, какие объемы сообщений?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы строчку, в которой происходит ошибка. Эта информация зачастую куда полезнее текста ошибки :)

Comment: Попробуйте не закрывать RequestStream до того, как пришел ответ (т.е. уберите один "dataStream.Close();"). Иначе получается, что stream уже закрылся, а данные еще не совсем послались.